# Using a working AWS API Gateway REST API to make a post request in javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, rest, google-chrome-extension, aws-api-gateway

I currently have a working REST API that I can test using Postman, however, I now need to integrate it into a google chrome extension project I am working on in javascript. In Postman I send a test result such as

```
{
    "userid":"343242342342",
    "links" : "[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II,https://www.hgtv.com/design/make-and-celebrate/handmade/how-to-make-a-paper-airplane,https://recipes.timesofindia.com/us/recipes/homemade-cake/rs54404412.cms]"
}
```

and inputted my secret keys I got from AWS. Beyond the secret keys, the API has no headers/authorization as it is just an alpha version and security is not an issue right now. I have an invoke URL but I am unsure how I can use this to create a POST method in javascript. I have tried looking up tutorials and documentation but I have not had any success. Does anyone know of any documentation of using API gateway in chrome extensions or any idea on how I can send a POST request in javascript to a REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this is by using fetch:

```
    //Your API
    const API = 'yourapi.com';

    //The data you are sending to API Gateway/Lambda
    const sendData = {userid: '343242342342', links: '[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_II,https://www.hgtv.com/design/make-and-celebrate/handmade/how-to-make-a-paper-airplane,https://recipes.timesofindia.com/us/recipes/homemade-cake/rs54404412.cms]'};
    
    //Your post request using FETCH
    fetch(API, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(sendData),
            })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((json) => {
                console.log(json);
                });
            })
```

Note: You might run into CORS issues along the way so make sure you have that enabled on your API Gateway endpoint/resource. You don't need to worry about AUTH like you would with postman.